# Формирование отчёта с видео и картинками в windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, файлы, видео

Мне в приложении нужна функция для создания отчёта из разного количества видео, скриншотов и текста, в формате, который сможет открыть встроенное в windows ПО. Программу думаю писать на C# или C++. Сами видео должны храниться внутри отчёта, а не быть ссылкой на файл, вот на этом моменте я не уверен что делать, **какой формат файла выбрать для отчёта?**

Comment: Определиться с форматом результирующего отчета не предлагать?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим вам обязательно чтобы отчет был одним файлом?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так вопрос и в том, какой использовать формат

Comment: @МишаковМаксим формат aspx?

Comment: @Arantler а вот об этом я не подумал, наверное это и будет решением, просто всё в архив закинуть

Comment: @МишаковМаксим просто вам подойдет архив с файлами, устроенными как скаченная HTML. Вроде в архиве при нажатии как-то можно настроить, чтобы открывалась указанный файл. Можете сделать отчет в формате exe, в котором бы лежал архив, а при нажатии открывался бы отчет в браузере(открывалась страница).

Comment: Ну так бы и написали: "как формат юзать, чтобы внутре и то и то было", а то у вас "есть какие - нибудь предложения?" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю должны подойти:

- **pdf** - в него можно вкладывать любое содержимое, его отображение весьма стандартно и оно открывается современными браузерами (в том числе Edge).
- упакованная веб-страница - это форматы **chm** и **mht**. Стоит учесть, что mht открывается только в IE, Edge (не проверял его, кстати) и Опере 12, а версию IE в просмотрищике chm я не помню - вполне может оказаться IE7.
- видеоформаты по типу dvd-дисков - там может быть меню и можно всё это дело упаковать в iso-образ, который десятка научилась монтировать в виде виртуального диска. Однако, помещать текстовую информацию на видео - это как-то бредово.
- Все офисные форматы. Предположу, что **rtf** тоже может подойти. Но он открывается везде по-разному так что так себе вариант.
- С **html** тоже можно поизвращаться, но объём может очень сильно увеличиться.
- Непосредственно **exe** или **swf** - сомнительный вариант в плане пересылки и возможности содержать внутри вирусы.

В общем, я бы выбирал между **pdf** и **mht** в зависимости от версии и умений ОС.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, в Вашем случае, проще всего будет форматировать отчет в HTML. В таком случае туда можно добавить и изображение, и музыку, и картинки, и форматированный текст. HTML можно открыть встроенными в Windows ПО: Interner Explorer, Edge. Так же это под силу реализовать даже среднему программисту в разумные сроки.

Правда "видео должны храниться внутри отчёта" вряд ли получится, да и вопрос, действительно ли это надо?

Comment: Почему бы тогда не скомпилированный HTML? Он ж как раз и есть архив со всеми ресурсами внутри

Comment: _"видео должны храниться внутри отчёта" вряд ли получится_ - mht или chm же.